# Open Graph Protocol. How to detect if is Facebook

Tags: facebook-opengraph

On LinkedIn [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/setting-display-tags-shares) "image must be at least 80 x 150 pixels". On Facebook [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) image "cannot exceed 130x110 pixels". I want to use a php function to resize a thumbnail for Facebook or LinkedIn.

How can I detect if is Facebook or LinkedIn when I share a link?

EDIT(Details):

When I paste a link to share it in Facebook or LinkedIn, they get the info that is in these tags inside the head of a html document:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="..." />
<meta property="og:description" content="..." />
<meta property="og:image" content="image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="id..." />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
```

For the og:image part for LinkedIn if is smaller then dimensions mentioned it will ignore it, while for Facebook the maximum required is smaller then what LinkedIn wants, and on Facebook for a wrong picture it looks to display a image of their own by default. So I'm trying to detect if I share a link on Facebook or LinkedIn to resize appropriate

Comment: I think you need to add some more detail to this question, what technologies are being used? what is the user journey?

Comment: I update it the question

Comment: OK so to make sure I understand correctly - When a user shares a link on Facebook it uses the open graph tags to generate a thumbnail for that link. I am not sure how LinkedIn does it but I am guessing from your question it does something similar however there is a size difference and you want to know how is best to solve this.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The problem is now that I have to chose either to display an image on LinkedIn or Facebook. The minimum required size  for LinkedIn is larger then maximum allowed on Facebook. I'll be happy to be able to detect one of them, when a link is shared.

Answer (score 3):

Look for the user agent of the request, if it's Facebook then serve the Facebook optimized image otherwise the default one (linkedin sizes).

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
```

Source: Open Graph Protocol, [Best Practices section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#crawl).

**NOTE:** While this is not the purpose of this user agent (it's not clear what is *allowed* and *not allowed*). But I ***think*** your purpose won't violate any platform policies.