# Exempt Facebook Crawler from .htaccess redirect

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, redirect

We recently forced all pages to be HTTPS through .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The problem is that I get "Circular redirect path detected" from Facebook debugger because the original URL is https, but the og:url is http (so we don't lose all of our old likes), and then it gets a 302 loop back to https.

How can I make Facebook an exception to this .htaccess rule?

Comment: Check their user agent, if the HTTP_USER_AGENT matches facebook you can turn off rewite engine or just skip that rewite.

Comment: How do I check the FB opengraph useragent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245028/open-graph-protocol-how-to-detect-if-is-facebook) addresses the user-agent that facebook external hits will look like. You just need to add a condition to check for it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/[0-9]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Should this still work ? I used this on a Joomla website which uses Cloudflare with force SSL but didnt work.

Comment: @9944990 The nature of CloudFlare's "Force SSL" is that CF tells the browser to redirect to HTTPS before your server has a chance to process those rules in the .htaccess. Therefore you would need to turn off "Force SSL" and let your .htaccess do the redirection.

Comment: I am adding same in my htaccess.. for now fb updates its not working