# Force og:url tag to use http url on https blog post

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I know it must be very easy but I somehow not able to achieve it. I have a wordpress site in which I have recently added SSL certficate to make it secure. But I lost all my like and shares. I want them to show in my post so I want to send http url in og:url tag. (Which is mentioned [Exempt Facebook Crawler from .htaccess redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164861/exempt-facebook-crawler-from-htaccess-redirect) in this post too.)

Is it possible somehow I can force my page to use http version of url in og:url open graph tag?

EDIT:
I have done suggested changes, but it still give me https url in "og:url" tag. please have a look on screenshots attached in the question. **I think problem is that the php file i am editing is inactive.**
[image]

[image]

I have tried deleting plugin then installing it again, then edited and activated the plugin but it still shows me PHP file I am editing as **inactive**

Comment: @PF Billing you may help.

Comment: share your code/function from where you are outputting open graph tags.

Comment: i dont know I am using ultimate seo plugin for the same.

Comment: all wordpress seo plugin adds their open graph tag automatically.

Comment: then there must be an option to chose that, i have used All in One SEO Pack there was an option for https and http.

Comment: no there is not. I think I have to edit some code?  but dont know what piece of code and where.

Comment: @RaunakGupta: I have tried all in one seo but it has option of canonical url setting not open graph meta tag "og:url". Plz help.

Comment: You have 2 option, first edit plugin; I have debug All in one seo, in `modules\aioseop_opengraph.php` line number 1207 and 1213 you have to use `str_replace` over there. otherwise disable og option and create your own og rendering tag. (recommended).

Comment: @RaunakGupta can you share your edits on modules\aioseop_opengraph.php

Comment: @RaunakGupta Also can you tell me this file shoing me inactive in editor. how to make it active?

Comment: replace 1206 line with `$home_url     = str_replace('https://', 'http://', esc_url( get_home_url() ));//esc_url( get_home_url() );` in `modules\aioseop_opengraph.php` file but this is not a good method to do it.

Comment: @RaunakGupta I think I am very close. i have done the changes but its not taking any affect. og:url is still https. Also module\aioseop_opengraph.php is showing me inactive. I have deleted and installed it again. but file is still showing me inactive. Can you tell me how to activate this file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123209/discussion-between-raunak-gupta-and-abdul-khalid).

Comment: @RaunakGupta waiting for your reply on chat.